# payment required after 30 days module

Tags: customer, payment-methods, invoice

hy for our exisiting customers we require that they pay after 30 days is there a module than only is visible for exisitng customers (so logged in).

And when they choose this option they receive an invoice at the last day? (so the 30th day) ?

or will this be some custom development.

Comment: You need to create custom payment method with such developent.